# UIKit setNeedsDisplayInRect: dirty rectangle not being respected

Tags: ios, uikit, drawrect

I'm working on an app where the user can toggle individual squares on and off in a grid that can potentially be hundreds of squares in each direction. I have a custom view that is drawing all the squares and is inside a `UIScrollView`'s content view. When the user taps a square, it's state changes, and I call a function on my view that computes the rectangle of dirty pixels that need to be redrawn, and calls `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:dirtyRect]` accordingly.

However, the next call to my view's `drawRect:` function is given a rect that is the same as the bounds of the view (which can be something like thousands of pixels in each direction). This causes a noticeable slowdown since we end up redrawing the entire view (potentially millions of pixels) instead of a single square that's less than a few hundred pixels.

To do a little digging and make sure I wasn't shooting myself in the foot somewhere, I overrode `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` so that I could print out the dirty rectangle and know when each was getting called:

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplayInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"setNeedsDisplayInRect: %f %f %f %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [super setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect];
}

- (void)setNeedsDisplay
{
    NSLog(@"setNeedsDisplay");
    [super setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

When I run my app, and tap on a square, I get the following logs:

```
2019-08-03 15:39:28.763032-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] done loading
2019-08-03 15:39:28.765756-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] setNeedsDisplay
2019-08-03 15:39:28.765851-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] setNeedsDisplay
2019-08-03 15:39:28.765995-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] setNeedsDisplay
2019-08-03 15:39:28.775883-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] setNeedsDisplay
2019-08-03 15:39:28.812023-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] drawRect: 0.000000 0.000000 4533.000000 5411.000000    // this is the initial draw for the full view as expected

2019-08-03 15:39:38.220319-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] processing toggle at row=371 col=337
2019-08-03 15:39:38.220890-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] setNeedsDisplayInRect: 2056.000000 2264.000000 6.000000 6.000000
2019-08-03 15:39:38.245801-0500 MyCoolApp[4923:4191214] drawRect: 0.000000 0.000000 4533.000000 5411.000000    // why is this the full view rect?
```

The first section of logs is from the view initializing and doing its first draw, and looks just fine. The second section is from me tapping a square to toggle it:

- we start processing the toggle action
- we set the dirty rect to the appropriate pixels
- we redraw

I'm curious why the dirty rectangle I'm being given is the full bounds of the view. Is it something to do with the fact that it's in a `UIScrollView`? My instincts say no since that should have been something that was optimized a long time ago.

Is there some way I can get access to the list of invalid/dirty rectangles in the view or put a breakpoint on it so I can see where it's getting updated?

Is there some fundamental way that things work that I'm just missing?

**Somewhat separate question:**
Is it okay to track my own internal dirty rects and only draw those in `drawRect:` regardless of what the passed in rectangle is, or is there no guarantee that my content in those areas may or may not already be drawn, or may have been cleared out?

**UPDATE:**

I've also done a bit of investigation into what happens if I simply choose not to draw the whole given dirty rect, and it turns out that the system is clearing the context after every draw! In this case it makes sense why I would be getting a rectangle different from my set dirty rect.

To try and prevent this, I tried setting `self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;`, but that didn't do anything and the view still clears out (I have the `backgroundColor` set to `UIColor.clearColor`). Is my understanding of that variable wrong? Given that changing the variable didn't help, I'm betting that whether or not the view is cleared out isn't really the issue here.

Comment: This is a well-asked question, and I've upvoted it for that reason, but isn't this why we have layers? If all these squares were individual layers none of this problem with redrawing the whole view would arise in the first place.

Comment: The main reason is that I'm not that familiar with layers and didn't know they were the preferred method in this type of drawing, but another is that I was worried that having hundreds of thousands of objects to iterate over might slow things down too much (although I didn't bother checking...). Now off to learn about layers!.

Comment: Well, that's a good thought. But you aren't going to have all of them onscreen at the same time. So it might not be a problem, and if it is, you can remove the ones that are offscreen after scrolling and add new ones only as they are about to be scrolled onto the screen. I wouldn't call layers "preferred" but it could end up being a lot simpler. It's certainly what I would try first, in any case.

Comment: They actually can all be on the screen at once. The app I'm working on is for cross stitching, so each square (stitch) is essentially a "pixel" in the larger picture/pattern, and the user can zoom all the way out to see the entire pattern at once. The only thing I know for sure wouldn't be an issue is to use OpenGL/Metal to render out two triangles for each square, but I've been trying to avoid that until I really really need it.

Comment: Aha, cool. Okay, so I don't really know whether this would put too great a strain on the rendering engine, but it is very easy to write an app that will test it. So you don't have to end up going any distance down this road if it turns out to be no good (and I won't feel guilty for having suggested it). — Another thing that might be useful to know about (not sure) is CATiledLayer which lets you supply different images at different degrees of zoom, and also lets you supply a piece of a large drawing lazily, i.e. only just when it scrolls into view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `CATiledLayer`! I overrode the `layerClass` property to return `[CATiledLayer class]` and everything is smooth now since it defaults to drawing only 256x256 tiles per `drawRect:` call. I even get a cool effect now of all the tiles fading in from the center outward during the initial draw as each tile finishes drawing. However, it does still have the same issue of requiring a redraw of an entire tile even when just a small part of the tile is invalidated, so although I now have a workaround, my question still stands.

Comment: Well yes but you could use smaller tiles.